# Understanding basic polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I've been trying to understand polynomials lately but find them tricky. There is a section in my textbook about them that I can't wrap my head around.

The book describes a polynomial $p(x)$ of the degree $m$ and $q(x)$ of the degree $n$. Then it is followed by a couple of statements you have to think about and find out which of them are true but no answer key is given.

1. $p(x)q(x)$ always has the degree $m+n$
2. The degree of $p(x)-q(x)$ is always $0$ if $m=n$
3. $p(x)^n$ has the degree $mn$
4. The degree of $(p(x)^2 - 1)/(p(x) - 1)$ is $m^2$ for all $x$ when $p(x) -1$ is not equal to $0$.
5. The degree of $p(x)+q(x)$ is the largest number of $m$ and $n$ if $m$ is not equal to $n$.

And I think that all of them should be true? But maybe not $4$?

Comment: Some of what you said does not strike me as true. For instance the difference of two polynomials of the same degree has degree zero is false.

Comment: It also depends on where the coefficients are taken from.

Comment: One or two of these should fall apart quickly if you just try a fre examples.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Some people assign the degree of $p(x) = 0$ to be $-\infty.$  If you don't do that, then I think all the statements are false.  To answer we really need to know, in this context, what the degree of $0$ is.

Answer (score 0):

Statement $2$ is false. In statement $4$, the degree of the quotient will be $m$ except when $p(x)=-1, $ in which case the quotient is $0$ and the degree is undefined.

Comment: Though the formulation “… is $m^2$ for all $x$ …” does not even make sense. And $m$ is also wrong in 4 for the zero polynomial as $-\infty\ne0$